# MySQL - SELECT Count DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, select, count, distinct

I have a **"work"** table with the following fields:

- work_id
- work_pop_id
- work_log
- work_lock

I would like to display for each DISTINCT **"work_pop_id"** the number of records in the table.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select work_pop_id, count(work_id) as work_prop_count
from `work`
group by work_pop_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(work_id)
from work
group by work_pop_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,

COUNT is displayed, but I do not know how "work_pop_id" this corresponds